# Silverlight Combobox - Setting the SelectedItem MVVM

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, mvvm

I have a ViewModel that sets the value for the "UserStructure" property. The problem is that the combobox wont bind to the value.

```
public class OwnerOccupierAccountViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Load combobox structures
    /// </summary>
    private readonly LoadOperation<Structure> _loadStructures;

    private readonly LoadOperation<UnitOccupierDetail> _loadUnitOccupierDetails;

    //public ICommand SaveAccountSettingsCommand { get; set; }

    #region Properties

    private ObservableCollection<Structure> _structures;
    public ObservableCollection<Structure> Structures
    {
        get { return _structures; }

        set
        {
            _structures = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Structures");
        }
    }

    private Structure _userStructure;
    public Structure UserStructure
    {
        get { return _userStructure; }
        set
        {
            _userStructure = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedStructure");
        }
    }

    private UnitOccupierDetail _unitOccupierDetail;
    public UnitOccupierDetail UnitOccupierDetail
    {
        get { return _unitOccupierDetail; }
        set
        {
            _unitOccupierDetail = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("UnitOccupierDetail");
        }
    }


    #endregion

    public OwnerOccupierAccountViewModel()
    {
        // SaveAccountSettingsCommand = new DelegateCommand(SaveAccountSettings, CanSave);

        UserAccountContext _userAccountContext;

        if (!DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
        {
            var loggedInUser = new Guid(WebContext.Current.User.UserID.ToString());

            _userAccountContext = new UserAccountContext();

            #region load structures
            _loadStructures = _userAccountContext.Load(_userAccountContext.GetStructuresQuery());
            _loadStructures.Completed += _loadStructuresCompleted;
            #endregion

            #region load user data 
            _loadUnitOccupierDetails =
                _userAccountContext.Load(
                    _userAccountContext.GetUnitOccupierDetailsQuery().Where(
                        u => u.UserIDFK == loggedInUser && u.StructureFK == 92));
            _loadUnitOccupierDetails.Completed += _loadUnitOccupierDetails_Completed;
            #endregion
        }
    }

    void _loadUnitOccupierDetails_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _unitOccupierDetail= new UnitOccupierDetail();
        _unitOccupierDetail = _loadUnitOccupierDetails.Entities.First();

        _userStructure = _unitOccupierDetail.Structure;
    }

    void _loadStructuresCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var theseStructures = new ObservableCollection<Structure>(_loadStructures.Entities);
        Structures = theseStructures;
    }

    //private void SaveAccountSettings(object param)
    //{

    //}

    //private static bool CanSave(object param)
    //{
    //    return true;
    //}
}

 <ComboBox x:Name="cboApartments" 
                          ItemsSource='{Binding Structures, Mode=TwoWay}'
                          DisplayMemberPath='StructureName'
                          SelectedValuePath='IDStructure'
                          SelectedItem='{Binding SelectedStructure,Mode=TwoWay}'
                          Width="200"
                          Height="25">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XAML SelectedItem is bound to SelectedStructure instead of UserStructure what you want

**UPDATE:**

Your code doesn't work because you should set to SelectedItem object that has reference equality with some object in ItemsSource. In your ViewModel you set Structures as result of one service operation and UserStructure as result of the other. UserStructure and some object in Structures can be equals (object.Equals) but not reference equals (object.ReferenceEquals). ComboBox like other ItemsControls doesn't compare items by equality, it compares they by identity. So, to have right code you should select from Structures object that equals to UserStructure and set it as UserStructure:

```
   void _loadUnitOccupierDetails_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        ...

        Structure userStructure = Structures.FirstOrDefault(s=>s.Equals(_unitOccupierDetail.Structure));
        UserStructure = userStructure;
   }
```

In this case you should be sure that Structures comes before. You can look at Reactive Extensions Observable.ForkJoin() method to syncronize 2 async calls.

Comment: Yes, I have corrected that and the RaisePropertyChanged event...  The combobox will still not bind

Comment: ItemsSource='{Binding Structures, Mode=TwoWay}': use ItemsSource='{Binding Structures}' instead

Comment: Replace _userStructure = _unitOccupierDetail.Structure; to UserStructure = _unitOccupierDetail.Structure; in viewmodel

Comment: Thanks Vladimir - one of your recommended changes made it work!!

Answer (score 2):

in xaml   UserStructure instead SelectedStructure.

Answer (score 0):

Try such changes

```
public class OwnerOccupierAccountViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Load combobox structures
    /// </summary>
    private readonly LoadOperation<Structure> _loadStructures;

    private readonly LoadOperation<UnitOccupierDetail> _loadUnitOccupierDetails;

    //public ICommand SaveAccountSettingsCommand { get; set; }

    #region Properties

    private ObservableCollection<Structure> _structures;
    public ObservableCollection<Structure> Structures
    {
        get { return _structures; }

        set
        {
            _structures = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Structures");
        }
    }

    private Structure _userStructure;
    public Structure UserStructure
    {
        get { return _userStructure; }
        set
        {
            _userStructure = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("UserStructure");
        }
    }

    private UnitOccupierDetail _unitOccupierDetail;
    public UnitOccupierDetail UnitOccupierDetail
    {
        get { return _unitOccupierDetail; }
        set
        {
            _unitOccupierDetail = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("UnitOccupierDetail");
        }
    }


    #endregion

    public OwnerOccupierAccountViewModel()
    {
        // SaveAccountSettingsCommand = new DelegateCommand(SaveAccountSettings, CanSave);

        UserAccountContext _userAccountContext;

        if (!DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
        {
            var loggedInUser = new Guid(WebContext.Current.User.UserID.ToString());

            _userAccountContext = new UserAccountContext();

            #region load structures
            _loadStructures = _userAccountContext.Load(_userAccountContext.GetStructuresQuery());
            _loadStructures.Completed += _loadStructuresCompleted;
            #endregion

            #region load user data 
            _loadUnitOccupierDetails =
                _userAccountContext.Load(
                    _userAccountContext.GetUnitOccupierDetailsQuery().Where(
                        u => u.UserIDFK == loggedInUser && u.StructureFK == 92));
            _loadUnitOccupierDetails.Completed += _loadUnitOccupierDetails_Completed;
            #endregion
        }
    }

    void _loadUnitOccupierDetails_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _unitOccupierDetail= new UnitOccupierDetail();
        _unitOccupierDetail = _loadUnitOccupierDetails.Entities.First();

        _userStructure = _unitOccupierDetail.Structure;
    }

    void _loadStructuresCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var theseStructures = new ObservableCollection<Structure>(_loadStructures.Entities);
        Structures = theseStructures;
    }

    //private void SaveAccountSettings(object param)
    //{

    //}

    //private static bool CanSave(object param)
    //{
    //    return true;
    //}
}

 <ComboBox x:Name="cboApartments" 
                          ItemsSource='{Binding Structures, Mode=TwoWay}'
                          DisplayMemberPath='StructureName'
                          SelectedValuePath='IDStructure'
                          SelectedItem='{Binding UserStructure,Mode=TwoWay}'
                          Width="200"
                          Height="25">
```

**Updated:**

Hmm, maybe try changes here:

```
     <ComboBox x:Name="cboApartments" 
                              ItemsSource='{Binding Structures, Mode=TwoWay}'
                              SelectedItem='{Binding UserStructure, Mode=TwoWay}'
                              Width="200"
                              Height="25">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=StructureName}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Hi Pawel - I made 2 corrections : RaisePropertyChanged("UserStructure"); and SelectedItem='{Binding UserStructure,Mode=TwoWay}' .... The combobox wont bind

Comment: I added new proposal for your problem

Comment: Hi Pawel - I replaced the combobox with your code - still not binding

Comment: Just to clarify, the combox is binding with initial values but the UserStructure property is not binding to the selecteditem.

Comment: Hmm so after you change selection in combobox, UserStructure property doesn't change? Try instead of binding to UserStructure binding directly to UnitOccupierDetail.Structure. SelectedItem='{Binding UnitOccupierDetail.Structure, Mode=TwoWay}'

Comment: This comment above is incorrect, but i still don't have any clue what could went wrong.

Comment: See Validimir's posts - I think removing the Mode=TwoWay did the trick